# Cuda kernel result goes wrong when I vary the matrix size

Tags: cuda, gpu, race-condition

Very simple kernel to compute:

```
tmp = X*y; 
tmp = sigmoid(temp)-L; 
y=transpose(X)*tmp;
```

However,sometimes it returns correct results, sometimes it returns wrong results, sometimes for 1000*1000 size problem, it returns correct results, but when I increase the problem size, it returns wrong results. It seems it has some race condition. But all the data is constrained by tid. Could you help me find out what is the bug?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define BLOCK_ROWS 512 

__global__ void MVM(int trows, int tcols, float *d_x, float *d_y, float *d_l, float *d_out)
{
        int tid = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x;
        if(tid < trows) {
                d_out[tid]=0;
                for(int i=0; i<tcols; i++)
                {
                        d_out[tid] = d_out[tid] + d_x[i*trows+tid]*d_y[i];
                }
                d_out[tid] = 1.0/(exp(-d_out[tid])+1.0)-d_l[tid];
         
        }

        __syncthreads;

        if(tid < tcols) {
                d_y[tid] =0; 
                for(int i=0; i<trows; i++)
                {
                        d_y[tid]  = d_y[tid] + d_x[tid*trows+i]*d_out[i];
                }
        }
}
int main(void)
{
  int trows = 100; int tcols = 100;
  float *x, *y, *out, *l, *d_x, *d_y, *d_out, *d_l, *check, *check1;
  x = (float*)malloc(trows*tcols*sizeof(float));
  y = (float*)malloc(tcols*sizeof(float));
  l = (float*)malloc(trows*sizeof(float));
  out = (float*)malloc(tcols*sizeof(float));
  check = (float*)malloc(trows*sizeof(float));
  check1 = (float*)malloc(tcols*sizeof(float));

  int result=0;
  result = cudaMalloc(&d_x, trows*tcols*sizeof(float));
  if(result!=cudaSuccess) printf("GPU allocation fail\n");
  result = cudaMalloc(&d_y, tcols*sizeof(float));
  if(result!=cudaSuccess) printf("GPU allocation fail\n");
  result = cudaMalloc(&d_out, trows*sizeof(float));
  if(result!=cudaSuccess) printf("GPU allocation fail\n");
  result = cudaMalloc(&d_l, trows*sizeof(float));
  if(result!=cudaSuccess) printf("GPU allocation fail\n");

  for(int j = 0; j <  tcols; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < trows; i++)
                x[j*trows+i] = (float)(i%10);
  }

  for(int i=0; i<tcols; i++) y[i] = (float)(i%10);

  for(int i=0; i<trows; i++) l[i] = (float)((trows-i)%10);

  result = cudaMemcpy(d_x, x, trows*tcols*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  if(result!=cudaSuccess) printf("cpying to GPU fail\n");
  result = cudaMemcpy(d_y, y, tcols*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  if(result!=cudaSuccess) printf("cpying to GPU fail\n");
  result = cudaMemcpy(d_l, l, trows*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  if(result!=cudaSuccess) printf("cpying to GPU fail\n");

  int grid=0;
  if(trows>tcols) grid = (trows-1)/BLOCK_ROWS+1; else grid = (tcols-1)/BLOCK_ROWS+1;
  dim3 dimGrid(grid,1,1);
  dim3 dimBlock(BLOCK_ROWS,1,1);

  clock_t t;
  t = clock();
  MVM<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>(trows, tcols, d_x, d_y, d_l, d_out);
  t = clock()-t;
  double time = ((double)t)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
  printf("time: %f\n", time);
  
    for(int i=0; i<trows; i++) {
        float tmp = 0;
        for(int j=0; j<tcols; j++)
                tmp += x[j*trows+i]*y[j];
        tmp = 1.0/(exp(-tmp)+1.0) - l[i];
        check[i] = tmp;
  }
  for(int i=0; i<tcols; i++) {
        float tmp = 0;
        for(int j=0; j<trows; j++)
                tmp = tmp+ x[i*trows+j]*check[j];
        check1[i] = tmp;
  }

  result = cudaMemcpy(out, d_y, tcols*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  if(result!=cudaSuccess) printf("cpying to CPU fail, error=%d\n",result);

  float error=0;
  for(int i=0; i< tcols;i++) {
        error += abs(check1[i]-out[i])/(abs(check1[i])+1e-6);
  }
  printf("error = %f\n", error);

  cudaFree(d_x);
  cudaFree(d_y);
  cudaFree(d_out);
  cudaFree(d_l);
  free(x);
  free(y);
  free(l);
  free(out);
  free(check);
  free(check1);
}
```

Comment: How are we supposed to know what is right and wrong?  Whenever I run your code, I get error = 0.  Even if I increase trows and tcols to 1000, I get error = 0.  Also, note that `__syncthreads;` is supposed to be `__syncthreads();`

Comment: I have found the problem. __syncthreads() is the one the problems. Another problem is the second matrix-vector multiplication uses the data having not been generated by the first matrix-vector multiplication, because __syncthreads() is only for block. The block 1 in second matrix-vector multiplication uses the data from the last block of first matrix-vector multiplication. So I see a undeterministic behavior  and  feel like a race condition. If I put the second MV multiplication in another kernel. It works correctly.

Answer (score -2):

Try changing the value of 'BLOCK_ROWS' for 'dim3 dimBlock', like 'trows' above.

```
dim3 dimBlock(trows,1,1); // instead of dim3 dimBlock(BLOCK_ROWS,1,1);
```

If elements in each column are processed together, setting blockDimX equal to the number of rows can usually avoid problems caused by '__syncthreads();'